# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'complete' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['complete/<todo_id>']

Tags: python, django, django-urls

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url('', views.index, name= 'index'),
url('add', views.addTodo, name ='add'),
url('complete/<todo_id>', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
url('deletecomplete', views.deleteCompleted, name='deletecomplete'),
url('deleteall', views.deleteAll, name='deleteall')
]
```

views.py( portion of a program)

```
def completeTodo(request, todo_id):
todo = Todo.objects.get(pk=todo_id)
todo.complete = True
todo.save()

return redirect('index')
```

index.html(portion of program) I guess this is where the problem is coming.

```
 <ul class="list-group t20">
                    {% for todo in todo_list %}
                        {% if todo.complete %}
                        <li class="list-group-item todo-completed">{{ todo.text }}</li>
                        {% else %}
                        <a href="{% url 'complete' todo.id %}"><li class="list-group-item">{{ todo.text }}</li></a>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex expression is wrong:

Instead of this:

```
url('complete/<todo_id>', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

try this:

```
url(r'^complete/(?P<todo_id>\d+)$', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

Or in case you want to use [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path)

```
path('complete/<int:todo_id>', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

**EDIT**

Since you're using Django 1.*, you can't use `path()`
The correct way to set up all your URLs is with `url` regex expressions

**Note**

> '^': The match must start at the beginning of the string or line.
>
> '$': The match must occur at the end of the string
>
> '\d+': Match all digits
>
> The `r` at the beginning stands for `regex`

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name= 'index'),
url(r'^add$', views.addTodo, name ='add'),
url(r'^complete/(?P<todo_id>\d+)$', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
url(r'^deletecomplete$', views.deleteCompleted, name='deletecomplete'),
url(r'^deleteall$', views.deleteAll, name='deleteall')
```

Comment: Thanks man. Can you also give me the correct regex expression for rest of the urls. I am new to django. I use D 1.11.13.

Answer (score 2):

Well you wrote a path like:

```
    url('complete/<todo_id>/', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

But here `<todo_id>` is part of the **url**, it does *not* denote a variable, etc. it means that there is only one url that will match: `/complete/<todo_id>`.

In case you use [django-2.x](/questions/tagged/django-2.x), you probably want to use **`path(..)`** instead:

```
    path('complete/<todo_id>', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

Furthermore in case `todo_id` is typically an integer, it is advisable to specify the type:

```
    path('complete/<int:todo_id>', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

For [django-1.x](/questions/tagged/django-1.x), you can not use such `path(..)`s, and in that case you need to **write a regular expression**, like:

```
    url(r'^complete/(?P<todo_id>[0-9]+)$', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I am new to Django. I am using Django version 1.11.13. I corrected the expression as suggested. still I am not able to add,deletecomplete,deleteall ( please give me correct regex expression for that)).

Comment: Well since I don't know the corresponding views, etc. that's impossible. But I *guess* you need to add `(?P<todo_id>[0-9]+)$` to it as well.

Comment: well does views.py corresponds to correct version of the django that I'm using ? I use 1.11.13

Comment: @AdarshBahadur: what if you add a `$` at the end of every regex and a `^` in front?

Comment: @AdarshBahadur: what is the template tag that produces the error?

Comment: No error whatsoever is coming. when i input a task and press add button nothing gets added.

Comment: @AdarshBahadur: well that is probably the expected behavior. Where do you specify what the button is supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks man. Every things working fine now. I suppose the error was in the url's regex expression. Simply resarting the server solved the problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: still If you see this. the app is working fine. But I am not able to see the values entered into the form in the server terminal. Am I not supposed to see it ?

Comment: @AdarshBahadur: well your view does not `print` anything, so you only see by default the logging that someone requested a certain URL.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, Here is the solution :

As your model name is Todo (Capital T) you are fetching the ID of each Tudo but in the views, URLs & template you are writing small (t). It becomes case sensitive.

Change the name (todo_id) to (Todo_id) everywhere in the views URLs and HTML template.

Here it is :

**urls.py**

```py
url('complete/<Todo_id>', views.completeTodo, name='complete'),
```

**template.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'complete' Todo.id %}">
```

**views.py**

```
def completeTodo(request, Todo_id):
    todo = Todo.objects.get(pk=Todo_id)
```